# c++ getline(cin) not popping for input

Tags: c++, cin, getline

So i have this funcion that asks for input if player wants to play again ->

```
bool AskToPlayAgain()
{
cout << "Play again?\n";
string PlayerResponse = "";

getline(cin, PlayerResponse);

cout << "First Character: " << PlayerResponse[0];
cout << endl;

return false;   }
```

This function works on its own, but i put it after my main game function it just skips it. My main game function is -->

```
void PlayGame(){
Initialize();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << "Introduce your word guess in 5 attempts: \n";
    cin >> GuessWord;

    if (GuessWord == Word)
    {
        cout << "Correct Guess!!!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Wrong Guess!!!\n";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

cout << "Correct word is " << Word;
cout << endl;

return;}
```

So yes, not sure why it does that.

Comment: it is not clear what you think is "skipped" here, because you are not calling the function `AskToPlayAgain`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including input, output and expected output

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction

Comment: @idclev463035818 Im calling both in main function

Comment: it is always better to post a complete example. Anyhow the problem and solution are explained in the q&a I linked above

Comment: @idclev463035818i see, im reading it now, thank you